# How to create multiple instances of a Zustand store?

Tags: reactjs, zustand

I'm making a map in a component and in this component I'm using Zustand to store the state of each component, the problem is that the store instance is the same for all items, how do I create a new instance for each item?

I've already tried to create a function to do this but it didn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE:

Zustand doing some updates on their documentation since ver.4 was released. This is in their documentation how to create multiple instance with **Slice Pattern**
https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/docs/guides/typescript.md#slices-pattern

## OLD ANSWER:

You can create multiple stories by setup it with different name of store.

Source code: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-breeze-jshevq

1. In this example I have created two store (bears and cats) files
   [image: Create two store files]
2. Initial zustand store for "bears" and "cats"
   [image: Inital zustand store]
3. Implementation
   [image]

Result: 
[image]

Comment: From the docs https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/docs/guides/flux-inspired-practice.md, they recommend create a single store and group them with the slice pattern, do you know why this is the best practice?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that they are doing a lot of updates in documentation for the Version 4 on August. This not the best practice from them but you still can use it. I have updated my answer, thank you

Comment: This is not creating multiple instances from the same store, this is copying & pasting into two stores

Comment: Slices are also not providing any solution here. slices refers to distinct elements within a single store, not multiple instances of the same store

Comment: This is not the answer to the question.

Comment: @BlabzX yeah you can downvote it if this is not the right one :)

Comment: @LiamSchauerman if you looking for creating multiple instances, check my oldest answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71679066/how-to-create-multiple-instances-of-a-zustand-store/72654447?noredirect=1#comment133202237_72654447:~:text=md%23slices%2Dpattern-,OLD%20ANSWER%3A,-You%20can%20create

Comment: Quoting the author himself, "use as many stores as you feel comfortable with" https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/ogdkhl/comment/h4ibw4q/ . BTW, having multiple slices doesn't mean you have multiple stores

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the definition of your state separate from when you instantiate it.

```
interface MyState {
  bears: number;
  setBears: (value: number) => void;
  getBears: () => number;
  killBears: () => void;
}

const definition = (
  set: (
    partial:
      | MyState
      | Partial<MyState>
      | ((state: MyState) => MyState | Partial<MyState>),
    replace?: boolean | undefined
  ) => void,
  get: () => MyState
) => ({
  bears: 0,
  setBears: (value: number) => set({ bears: value }),
  getBears: () => get().bears,
  killBears: () => set({ bears: 0 }),
} as MyState);

export const useState1 = create<MyState>(definition);
export const useState2 = create<MyState>(definition);
```

Comment: I think this is the same as my old answer :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71679066/how-to-create-multiple-instances-of-a-zustand-store/72654447?noredirect=1#comment133202237_72654447:~:text=md%23slices%2Dpattern-,OLD%20ANSWER%3A,-You%20can%20create

Comment: @detautama I don't believe so since this one has the SAME definition but DIFFERENT instances. Your example has DIFFERENT definitions (e.g. the variable cat in one and bear in another)