# Multiple versions of the same store in Zustand

Tags: reactjs, zustand

I would like to create a store in Zustand that takes a string argument (character name) and create a version of that store per name. Then, I could have multiple stores and call each store corresponded to the inputted character name.

I saw that this could be done using slice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72654447/13127928) answer. But they are creating each store manually. I want to have the store as a template and assign an initialized version of it to each inputted name.

I've tried something like this:

```
export const useCharacterStore = (characterName: string) => createWithEqualityFn(
....
)
```

But this did not work, and I don't know how to recall a desired store.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the store in the component and pass it down via `React.Context`. The problem is that on each render new store gets created. As a solution to this, you can use `useMemo`

Zustand also provides a context provider for such a case https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/previous-versions/zustand-v3-create-context

```
const createStore = () =>
  create((set) => ({
    bears: 0,
    increasePopulation: () => set((state) => ({ bears: state.bears + 1 })),
    removeAllBears: () => set({ bears: 0 })
  }));

const Button = () => {
  return (
      {/** store() - This will create a store for each time using the Button component instead of using one store for all components **/}
    <Provider createStore={createStore}>
      <ButtonChild />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

As you can see from their example, the store is created inside the component, their Provider does that, it accepts a function that returns the store, not the store itself

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I actually got inspired with a solution and created a map `const characterStores = new Map();` to include all stores there.

But now I'm facing another problem when updating a state:
`const marioStore = useCharacterStore('Mario');`
`marioStore.setProgress("Dungeons", 6);`
This returned error:
[zustand persist middleware] Unable to update item 'Mario-activities-storage', the given storage is currently unavailable.